# Perl metaprogramming: when is it unsafe to use quotemeta on the REPLACEMENT value of s///?

Tags: regex, perl, metaprogramming

Perl's [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) operator typically works on the SEARCH side of `s///`, but in generating code to be compiled with [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html), how should I protect the REPLACEMENT that should be used literally but may contain bits such as `$1`?

With code of the form

```
my $replace = quotemeta $literal_replacement;

my $code = eval <<EOCode;
  sub { s/.../$replace/ }
EOCode
```

when will it produce syntax errors or surprising results?

Comment: Why in the world are you doing that?

Comment: @Chas It's a lot like the technique used in the example in perlfunc's entry on [`study`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/study.html).

Comment: Are you sure that isn't premature optimization?  You are opening yourself to a ton of problems with this and I doub't it will have a significant impact on your runtime.

Comment: Why are you even using string eval? Just do my $code = sub { s/.../$literal_replacement/ }; this wll NOT interpolate the contents of $literal_replacement, just use it as a literal replacement string.

Comment: @MkV - I understood his question that he wants $1 to be working inside the string, but nothing else. - I'm not sure how to guarantee that without coding that behavior explicitly.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can tell, perl doesn't do magic things with $replace as long as you don't add the /e flag on the substitute. So quotemeta will always change your result, as it then contains a lot of backslashes.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$test="test";

$literal_replacement='Hello $1, or \1';
my $replace = quotemeta $literal_replacement;
$test =~ s/test/$replace/;

print $test,"\n";
```

returns:

```
Hello\ \$1\,\ or\ \\1
```

Which is probably not what you want :

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I asked my question poorly, leaving out important context. Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

The replacement side is a normal interpolating string (unless you start adding `/e` modifiers, in which case it becomes as many string `eval`s as there are `/e` modifiers.).  Perl 5 does not care what is in the variable you interpolate into the string.  It is the same as:

```
my $foo = 5;
my $bar = '$foo';
my $baz = "$foo $bar"; 
print "$baz\n"; #this is 5 $foo not 5 5
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I asked my question poorly, leaving out important context. Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

The replacement is usually processed like a double-quoted string, but you can change that by using single-quotes as the delimiter:

```
$test =~ s<test>'$replace';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I asked my question poorly, leaving out important context. Please see the updated question.

Comment: I don't think I can help you there.  I can't even imagine why you would want to do that.