# Perl substitution output drops characters from Bash script input

Tags: regex, perl, bash

I have a variable in a bash script with a length of 64 characters

```
authkey=$(LC_ALL=C tr -cd 'a-zA-Z0-9,;.:_#*+~!@$%&()=?{[]}|><-' < /dev/random | head -c 64)
```

if i parse the variable to perl to do a string substitution

```
perl -pi -e "s/'AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here'/'AUTH_KEY',         '$authkey'/" test.txt
```

depending on the selected random characters the length of the output differs.The output looks the following (The first string is the output in the resulting text file, the second string is the echo'ed output of the variable in the bash script)

```
q=dB7oUz59.IDBXI:i>ckW4oy3smX&k:-C.[rIf*9w}H=(N93yiB&nk{fP:y0_
q=dB7oUz59.IDBXI:i>ckW4oy3smX&k$s:-C.[rIf*9w}H=(N93yiB&nk{fP:y0_

5A+BwP~l3~<evp.ciTkMYtvmPjyMrL=):Qj1VaMI(,TSS,ZGMcd.m,4W
5A+BwP~l3~<evp.ciTkMYtvmPjyMrL=):Qj1VaMI(@Dk7UNgs,TSS,ZGMcd.m,4W

dX73}i5G1d;L*J=60WHHe<!61Ji_KJ)T5B~b2bCfaNDjBQr_N]}3HS=;GzAaX<gB
dX73}i5G1d;L*J=60WHHe<!61Ji_KJ)T5B~b2bCfaNDjBQr_N]}3HS=;GzAaX<gB

6Ndn(9+:>(6>*rh?B.m),3POp)>sfm8c1rh9vXr~fzZj;]!)kf3#60=M
6Ndn(9+:>(6>*rh?B.m),3POp)>sfm8c1rh9vXr~fzZj;]@YH!)kf3#$=$$ckt=M

FYMI,K|6WutC&dr-3]6)f(>QU-~{vBX>n!J-zq:kK84T|fZ7UW:{1&qU[nwYZLmC
FYMI,K|6WutC&dr-3]6)f(>QU-~{vBX>n!J-zq:kK84T|fZ7UW:{1&qU[nwYZLmC

5A+BwP~l3~<evp.ciTkMYtvmPjyMrL=):Qj1VaMI(,TSS,ZGMcd.m,4W
5A+BwP~l3~<evp.ciTkMYtvmPjyMrL=):Qj1VaMI(@Dk7UNgs,TSS,ZGMcd.m,4W

v1FR8c8}dZD(QGwOrr%M{FSUw*?h.JGI?Ay4tgRVp~l7C5eAxW<w<;c}emeX#S
v1FR8c8}dZD(QGwOrr%M{FSUw*?h.JGI?Ay4tgRVp@s~l7C5eAxW<w<;c}emeX#S

+MGg0=*NrhJ}.qPkk6v[lc)J.uiW1o?LL5t<HTC#Q-hSeqn%-ke!cwL5tk[e
+MGg$|=*NrhJ}.qPkk6v[lc)J.uiW1o?L$55L5t<HTC#Q-hSeqn%-ke!cwL5tk[e
```

each character dropout was caused by either a `$` or `@` at the beginning of the group of characters. Is there a way to prevent that behaviour? Best regards Ralf

Comment: Perl performs variable interpolation in the replacement string, and `$` and `@` are variable prefixes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694851/perl-metaprogramming-when-is-it-unsafe-to-use-quotemeta-on-the-replacement-valu for a related issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a single quote `'` as the delimiter instead of slash `/` for the substitution suppresses variable interpolation

```
$ foobar=\$bar; perl -p -e "s'foo'$foobar'"
xx
xx
foo
$bar
^C
$
```

Unfortunately the single quotes that are matched in the substitution now need escaping

```
foobar=\$bar; perl -p -e "s'\'foo'$foobar\''"
x
x
'foo
$bar'
^C
```

But that seems to get passed through to Perl OK, without munging the authkey contents with sed

Answer (score 0):

You can escape `$` and `@` before calling perl:

```
 authey=$(echo -n "$authkey" | sed -re 's/(\$|\@)/\\\1/g')
```